# Updating django "notes" section with ajax

Tags: django, ajax

I've looked at docs and watched videos and asked another question on stack overflow but just can't understand how to use ajax with my django project. Essentially I have a list of territory managers that are returned from a for loop (here's the models.py, views.py and detail.html showing that):

`models.py`

```
class TM(models.Model): #Change this to territory manager and delete database and recreate
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 200,null=True)
    Cell = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null=True)
    EmailAddress = models.EmailField(null=True)
    Notes = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Distributor = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    Brand = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            if self.Distributor is not NullBooleanField:
                return self.Name + ' - ' + self.Distributor + ' - '  + self.State
        except TypeError: 
            return self.Name
```

`views.py`

```
def detail(request):
    
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            state = request.POST['state']
            brand = request.POST['brand']
            territory_manager = TM.objects.filter(State__icontains=state).filter(Brand__icontains=brand)
            return render(request,'homepage/detail.html', {'state': state, 'territory_manager':territory_manager})
        else:
            state = request.POST['state']
            brand = request.POST['brand']
            return render(request,'homepage/detail.html', f"No Results for {state} or {brand}")
    except TM.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Info Does Not Exist")
```

`table in detail.html`

```
<table class= "content-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Distributor</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Brand</th>
                            <th>Cell</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Notes</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        {% for tm in territory_manager %}
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{ tm.Name }}</td>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{ tm.Distributor }}</td>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{ tm.State }}</td>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{ tm.Brand }}</td>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{ tm.Cell }}</td>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">{{ tm.Email }}</td>
                            <td id='notes' contenteditable="True">{{ tm.Notes }}</td>
                            <td><button id="note_submit" type="button">Update</button></td>  
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
            
                        </tbody>
                </table>
```

It loads a page with territory managers' names, emails, phone and a notes section. I have made the notes section editable and want to use ajax so when someone edits the notes section and hits the update button that the updated note will be saved to the db and displayed to the user. I have tried piecing together several different SO answers to no avail. Here is what I have:

`script placed at the bottom of my detail.html`

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {   
                $(document).on("click",'.notes_submit', function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/ajax/",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {action: 'note_update', note: document.getElementById("notes").value},
                        success: function(data){
                            $("#notes").html("<strong>"+data.note+"</strong>");                
                            }
                    });
                });
            });
            
            </script>
```

`functions in views.py`

```
def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        return self.ajax(request)

def ajax(self, request):
    response_dict= {
        'success': True,
    }
    action = request.POST.get('action','')

    if action == 'note_submit':
        note_id = request.POST.get('id','')

    if hasattr(self, action):
        response_dict = getattr(self, action)(request)
        note = TM.objects.get(Note='note_id')
        response_dict = {
            'note_name':note.name
        }

    return render(simplejson.dumps(response_dict),
                        mimetype='application/json')
```

Any direction appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've omitted the url option in the ajax call. In that case the request is sent to the current page. In your case this would be the detail view, which doesn't handle the ajax request.

And replace the EventListener in your data option with the content of the notes.

```
$.ajax({
    url: // PUT THE URL TO YOUR AJAX HANDLING VIEW HERE //,
    type: "POST",
    data: {action: 'note_update', note: document.getElementById("notes").textContent;},
    success: function(data){
      $("#notes").html("<strong>"+data.note+"</strong>");                
      }
    });
```

Comment: thanks so much for responding! So does the url that I put in the ajax call have to lead to another .html template? Because I was trying to make the detail.html page just update without having to navigate away. I also have updated the `script placed at the bottom of my detail.html` section of the above post and tried to run it again and nothing happened. Is there maybe something else that I have mislabeled that you can see? Thanks! @yagus

Comment: No, the url should point to the view that is handling your ajax request. In your case it is the "ajax" view, which is not rendering a new template. This is a backend operation and not related to any html. I advise that you familiarize yourself with the basics of Django MVT design. Otherwise, it will be difficult to implement more advanced concepts such as ajax. @JustinBenfit

Comment: Ok thanks! I will do some more research